# eBay API CompleteSaleRequest failed with ErrorCode 21843

Tags: ebay-api

i want to update TrackingInformation within the CompleteSaleRequest but it returns "Invalid job context type"

what's wrong?  anyone got a hint?

Request:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CompleteSaleRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
   <RequesterCredentials>
      <eBayAuthToken>ABC...123</eBayAuthToken>
   </RequesterCredentials>
   <Shipped>true</Shipped>
   <ItemID>1234567890</ItemID>
   <TransactionID>99999999999</TransactionID>
   <OrderID>1234567890-99999999999</OrderID>
   <Shipment>
      <ShipmentTrackingDetails>
         <ShipmentTrackingNumber>12345678987654321</ShipmentTrackingNumber>
         <ShippingCarrierUsed>DHL</ShippingCarrierUsed>
      </ShipmentTrackingDetails>
   </Shipment>
</CompleteSaleRequest>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
   <Timestamp>2016-03-08T20:58:58.831Z</Timestamp>
   <Ack>Failure</Ack>
   <Errors>
      <ShortMessage>Invalid job context type</ShortMessage>
      <LongMessage>The job context object is not supported by Action Service Framework.</LongMessage>
      <ErrorCode>21843</ErrorCode>
      <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
      <ErrorParameters ParamID="0">
         <Value>GetOrders</Value>
      </ErrorParameters>
      <ErrorParameters ParamID="1">
         <Value>CompleteSaleRequestType</Value>
      </ErrorParameters>
      <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
   </Errors>
   <Version>953</Version>
   <Build>E953_INTL_APIXO_17829668_R1</Build>
</GetOrdersResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the response from eBay you will see that it is wrapped in *GetOrdersResponse* element. Since you are calling the *CompleteSale* operation you would expect it to be in a *CompleteSaleResponse* element.  The reason will be due to how eBay routes the API requests. Since all operations go to the same URL the server needs a way to determine which operation you are calling. This is done by looking at the **HTTP headers** of the request. The contents of the body are ignored during this routing. The value of the HTTP header *X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME* should contain the name of the operation that you are calling. I expect that at the moment it is *GetOrders*. If you set the header to *CompleteSale* the operation will be routed corrected and you should get the correct response.

Comment: Hey David, that was exactly the problem! Thanks for the Explanation, you saved my day!